# Passing a vector<vector<int>> into a function gives memory error

Tags: c++, function, graph

So I was writing a simple program in codeforces which uses a DFS to transverse and find a path from a S to D.
My DFS function is recursive function and comes in two forms.

```
 1. bool DFS(int u, int v, vector<vector<int>> nb)
 2. bool DFS(int u, int v)
```

In the first form (1.), I pass the agency list (nb) as an arguement for the function and in the second form (2.), I make nb a global variable so I don't need to pass nb as an arguement. However, (1.) gives me a memory limit whereas option 2 does not.

I was wondering, does passing nb as an argument copy the entire list. I propose this as this would explain the memory error. Or does it just copy the pointer address to the list? (If so, the problem must have been memory tight).

Problem: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/500/A
soln (1.) https://codeforces.com/contest/500/submission/83148365
soln (2.) https://codeforces.com/contest/500/submission/83148036

Comment: Pass by reference.

Comment: "I was wondering, does passing nb as an argument copy the entire list." - Yes, if you pass a vector (or most other types) by value you'll get a deepcopy.

Answer (score 2):

This function:

```
bool DFS(int u, int v, vector<vector<int>> nb)
```

takes the `vector` by copy, so yes, this can be very expensive.

Instead, you can take the `vector` argument by reference:

```
bool DFS(int u, int v, vector<vector<int>> & nb)
```

or even better, by const reference, if you don't want to change it:

```
bool DFS(int u, int v, vector<vector<int>> const & nb)
```